# open Emulator or data folder at my AVD Image

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I am using android studio 3 and I do not know Why I can not open Emulator and data folder from `Android device monitor`?
seems there is no file at these folders. but Emulator folders must have **0 folder** itself inside.

[image]

someone know why and how could I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Then the Android Device Monitor window will pop up. Click on the emulator & File Explorer.

Shared Preference files should be in:

DDMS-> File Explorer ->data -> data -> MY_PACKAGE_NAME -> shared_prefs -> YOUR_PREFERENCE_NAME.xml

[image]

Comment: is this helpful otherwise what's the problem ?

Comment: .there is no folder under data and emulator at my device monitor